# response.redirect to pdf file on server not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, response.redirect

I have a program that goes out and searches a server for PDF file then opens it in a users web browser.  Here is the code to open:

```
Response.Redirect("http://" & fileFoundPath & fileName)
```

Which brings up http://servername/E/drawings//1/2/3/123456.pdf which doesn't open the file.... however if I replace http:// with file:///// it works fine.  Is there an easy way in the program to tell its on a server and its a file not a website?

Comment: If this is on a local intranet, why not use the file:// path?

Comment: Why don't you create a virtual directory pointing to "drawings"?

Comment: http:// is going to direct it to treat the path as a web address. Local paths will need to use the file:// prefix or //[servername]/filename.ext or [driveLetter]:/filename.ext. You should know beforehand whether files you'll be accessing are on the web or local, and use the appropriate path

Comment: The reason I did http:// @soohoonigan is because otherwise it shows my web server address so this was just a trial attempt to get that working.  I've tried the file:// with no luck either.  This is on a server hosted in house actually.

Comment: Then `\\[Servername]\[Filepath]` should work fine...or better yet, use relative paths

Comment: I tried this: Response.Redirect("\\" & fileFoundPath & fileName) .. no such luck still shows my web server name

Comment: It has to to a mapped directory in your website. It cannot be any file in the server file system.